# AS3 decoding XML file

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I need some help decoding my XML file.
It looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<design>
    <images>
        <cell id="fill" file="cellImages/cellFill"/>
        <cell id="top" file="cellImages/cellTop"/>
        <cell id="topLeft" file="cellImages/cellTopLeft"/>
        <cell id="topRight" file="cellImages/cellTopRight"/>
        <cell id="bottom" file="cellImages/cellBottom"/>
        <cell id="bottomLeft" file="cellImages/cellBottomLeft"/>
        <cell id="bottomRight" file="cellImages/cellBottomRIght"/>
    </images>
</design>
```

and this is my code:

```
    function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void 
    { 
        _structXML = XML(_structLoader.data); 
        trace("Data loaded." + _structXML); 

        var a:XML;
        for each( a in _structXML.images.cell)
        {
            trace("test=" + a);
        }
    }
```

all it traces is the XML and 7 "test="
no data is traced from the XML.

Please help :)

Answer (score 1):

It traces empty strings for all `a` values because they're empty XML nodes (with no content but only attributes). Using `a.@file` should get you the image's file.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
trace("test id = " + a.attribute("id"));
trace("test file = " + a.attribute("file"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `"test=" + a` is converting the `a` XML object to a string, and per the [rules of XML `toString()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#toString%28%29):

> - If the XML object has simple content, `toString()` returns the String contents of the XML object with the following **stripped out: the start
>     tag, attributes, namespace declarations, and end tag.**
> - If the XML object has complex content, `toString()` returns an XML encoded String representing the entire XML object, including the start
>     tag, attributes, namespace declarations, and end tag.

Because your `<cell>` nodes has "simple" content (no child nodes), it strips out the XML start and end tag from the output, and because the `<cell>` nodes contain nothing, you get an empty string, which doesn't output anything visible in your `trace` statement.

You can use [`toXMLString()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#toXMLString%28%29) to get the full string representation of the XML (ie the second behavior listed above regardless if the node content is "simple" or "complex").

```
trace("test=", a.toXMLString());
```

Or you could output the attributes:

```
trace(a.@id, "=", a.@file);
```

(Note: `trace` can take multiple arguments, you don't need to use string concatenation with `+`.)